# Run python and anaconda python in cmd

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

On Windows I have two Python distributions installed:

- Anaconda Python 3.4 and
- Python 3.4.

I would like to access both distributions from command prompt (cmd), in example,`anaconda34` for Anaconda Python 3.4 and `python34` for Python 3.4. Similarilly I would like to access the other features, such as `pip`, `ipython`, `jupyter notebook` with one or the other version.  How can I do this?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

Answer (score 0):

Forget about your non-Anaconda Python. With (Ana)conda you can very easily manage multiple full blown isolated Python environments. Then you can switch between them by "activating" them, see http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#change-environments-activate-deactivate. It's like the clever way of @R-Nar's comment.